# Can I use Gauss Elimination if one of my rows is full of 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I'm trying to solve a linear system of equations and I choose to use Gauss Elimination. One of my rows is full of $1$. Can I use the Gauss Elimination? I have to use this row in the first line or in the last line?

Comment: What prevents you from doing Gauss elimination?

Comment: In the process of performing Gaussian Elimination, following for example the [algorithm described on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Pseudocode), absolutely no reference is made to whether or not you have a row of all ones.  You can of course perform gaussian elimination with *any* matrix, regardless of the values of the entries.

Comment: @Wojowu To your previous comment: Then just yes xdd

Comment: A similar comment bears repeating: Why do you think a row of ones would cause a problem?

Comment: LOL. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: as to your second question, it might be nice to make the row of 1's  your first row, because then the first element of the matrix is already 1 and you can move to the second step of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about the matrix with a row of identical nonzero values. The row could be the first row if that helps solving the system.

For example the system $$ x+y=1, 2x+3y=5/2$$is such a system with $x=y=1/2$